# How to instantiate lite mode beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

It is said in Spring docs, that [`@Bean` annotation can be applied to methods even in components and POJOs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

But how to instantiate those beans?

The following code throws `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Also it shows, that bean is constructed several times when method called (which is consistent with words about instrumentation, but not consistent with words about scope).

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

public class LiteModeBeans {

   public static class Database {
   }

   public static class MyClass {

      {
         System.out.println("Constructed");
      }

      private Database database;

      public Database getDatabase() {
         return database;
      }

      @Autowired
      public void setDatabase(Database database) {
         this.database = database;
         System.out.println("Database set");
      }
   }


   public static class LiteContainingBean {

      @Bean
      MyClass myClass() {
         return new MyClass();
      }

      public MyClass getMyClass() {
         return myClass();
      }
   }


   @Configuration
   public static class Config {

      @Bean
      Database database() {
         return new Database();
      }

      @Bean
      LiteContainingBean liteContainingBean() {
         return new LiteContainingBean();
      }


   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

      MyClass myClass;

      LiteContainingBean liteContainingBean = ctx.getBean(LiteContainingBean.class);
      myClass = liteContainingBean.myClass();
      myClass = liteContainingBean.myClass();

      myClass = ctx.getBean(MyClass.class); // No qualifying bean of type [com.inthemoon.snippets.springframework.LiteModeBeans$MyClass] is defined
      System.out.println("MyClass: " + myClass.toString());



   }

}
```

So, how to force bean of `MyClass` be created and processed via Spring?

**UPDATE**

The following worked, thanks `@MDeinum`:

```
public class LiteModeBeans {

   public static class Database {
   }

   public static class MyClass {

      {
         System.out.println("Constructed");
      }

      private Database database;

      public Database getDatabase() {
         return database;
      }

      @Autowired
      public void setDatabase(Database database) {
         this.database = database;
         System.out.println("Database set");
      }
   }


   @Component
   public static class LiteContainingBean {

      @Bean
      MyClass myClass() {
         return new MyClass();
      }

   }


   @Configuration
   public static class Config {

      @Bean
      Database database() {
         return new Database();
      }


   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class, LiteContainingBean.class);

      MyClass myClass;

      myClass = ctx.getBean(MyClass.class); // No qualifying bean of type [com.inthemoon.snippets.springframework.LiteModeBeans$MyClass1] is defined
      System.out.println("MyClass1: " + myClass.toString());



   }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to have it as a lite bean of a bean? You could just make it a regular full bean

Comment: I just wish to understand, how to use this documented feature.

Comment: Comparing to the example in the docs, you've got many extra factors there. You're embedding target classes, declaring them as `static` and using a `main` method in the same class. Why don't you try firstly to reproduce the case in the docs and later on expand it till you reach your current case?

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace, you possibly have a bad dependency in your code. MyClass depends on database that is created by Config class.

Comment: @XtremeBiker what do you mean? Code is as simple as posible, it is http://sscce.org/

Comment: Lite mode only works when component scanning. If you make your `LiteContainingBean` a `@Component` and remove the `@Bean` and use `@ComponentScan` instead it works as documented.

Comment: @6ton so, what? I expect it should be autowired by Spring. This would be an indication Spring is processing instance as a bean.

Comment: I suspect you got some problem with spring not scanning the `@Bean` method of `LiteContainingBean` because https://gist.github.com/zapl/950c7b20b10570f0048cde129968dad2 works.

Comment: @zapl yes you directly passed a bean class to context constructor, similar as @MDeinum suggested; and finally it worked event without `@Component` annotation; but probably in your code `LiteContainingBean` itself was not instantiated.

Comment: Yes, it seems it's roughly equivalent to putting `@Component`. `ctx.register(LiteContainingBean.class);` causes `Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'liteModeBeans.LiteContainingBean'`, which then created the `MyClass`. However if you add another level of `@Bean` like https://gist.github.com/zapl/db619c6a6938c5dfd9cace6d7c0cd3fb it stops working because bean post processing or something doesn't check for further sub beans.